# Get Entry from GZIPInputStream using Java

Tags: java, gzip, gzipinputstream

Is there a way to get entry from GZIPInputStream ?
For .zip files I am using the following:

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream((InputStream) inputStream);
ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();
```

But i want to exclude the entry inside file with .xml.gz extension.
Or is there a way to extract the data inside .xml.gz file as String ?

Comment: @marsouf Tha question is about ZIP. This one is about GZIP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GZIP files don't *have* entries. They have single payloads.